# apt update "does not have a Release file"

Tags: apt, ppa

I'm trying to fix this issue when running `sudo apt update`:

```
E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu loki Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I tried adding the correct repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository    "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   xenial \
   stable"
```

Also tried searching for the "loki" keyword and replace to "xenial", no luck:

```
lucaswxp@imhuman:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ cat * | grep "loki"
> empty result
```

Any idea how to get apt update to work again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I was looking in the wrong path. The file I needed to edit was `/etc/apt/sources.list`. I just replaced loki to xenial and it worked.